# How to separate number by its decimal point in Excel/Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I've got a number in a spreadsheet like so: `28.686279`

When I open this sheet in either LibreOffice Calc or Microsoft Excel, is there a formula function that returns the "whole number", I.e. 28. Also, is there a formula that returns the "decimal part", I.e. `0.686279`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`TRUNC()` is designed to remove the decimal part of any number immediately and without any modification to the non-decimal part.

So, as per [LinYan's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/280929/how-to-separate-number-by-its-decimal-point-in-excel-calc/280931#280931), you just need to use:

- `TRUNC(A1)` to obtain the integer part of the value in `A1`
- `A1-TRUNC(A1)` to obtain the fractional part of the value in `A1`

---

Unlike `FLOOR()`, `TRUNC()` works on both positive and negative numbers without requiring adjustment, and works in the same way in both Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice.

`FLOOR()` *requires* the significance parameter to have the same sign as the number being processed (or else will throw an error), so the `1` at the end would have to be changed to `-1` to process negative numbers, or you could insert `SIGN()` and unnecessarily complicate the formula further.

And, in OpenOffice and LibreOffice, `FLOOR()` also has an additional (compared to Excel) third "mode" parameter that changes the results that the function returns for negative numbers.

Answer (score 8):

you can try `FLOOR` function, `floor(A1,1)`  for integer part of A1, `A1-floor(A1,1)` for decimal part of A1.

Comment: Just wondering, why isn't there some form of FRAC(A1) function to retrieve the decimal part? It seems that's something people do quite often, right?

Comment: How about negatives...

Answer (score 5):

For example, imagine A1 is 167.583 :
`int(A1)` would give 167 and
`mod(A1,1)` would give 0.583 .

Comment: You do realise that `int(1.6) === 1` and `int(-1.6) === -2`... But `trunc(decimal;0)` works correctly for both.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's a specific function to do this, however by nesting a couple you can.

Assuming you're trying to return the right-of-decimal value for cell A1, the formula would be:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(".",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

Effectively what you're doing here is using the MID function to return some number of characters starting at the decimal point.  All 3 references to A1 need to be updated for each cell you're targeting for it to work correctly.

Comment: This returns text rather than a number.

Answer (score -3):

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(ABS(A1)-INT(ABS(A1));",00");2)
```

would'nt this be just perfect, and aesthetic, too?

Comment: This returns text rather than a number.